# What is the correct way to mock my function using Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am new to React/TypeScript and need help with my unit testing. I need full line coverage for the code in ReactErrorBoundary.tsx but my test is not able to correctly mock the objects.

ReactErrorBoundary.tsx:

```
export default function ReactErrorBoundary(props: { readonly children?: ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary
      FallbackComponent={ErrorPage}
      onError={(error) => {
        console.log("Error caught!");
        logger(error)
      }}
      onReset={() => {
        console.log("reloading the page...");
        window.location.reload();
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
}
```

This is my logger (logService.tsx):

```
export const logger = (message: any) => {
    console.log("This is the logger service " +
      (message?.message ? message.message : message));
}
```

These are the tests I have so far, in which only the first two pass:

```
import ReactErrorBoundary from '../../components/ReactErrorBoundary';
import { ErrorBoundary } from 'react-error-boundary';
import { logger } from '../../services/logService';
import ErrorPage from '../../components/ErrorPage';

jest.mock('../../services/logService', () => ({
  logger: jest.fn(),
}));

jest.mock('react-error-boundary', () => {
  const React = require('react');
  const ErrorPage = require('../../components/ErrorPage').default;

  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('react-error-boundary'),
    ErrorBoundary: jest.fn(({ onError, onReset, FallbackComponent }) => {
      onError && onError(new Error());
      onReset && onReset();

      return {
        FallbackComponent: ErrorPage,
      };
    }),
  };
});

describe('ReactErrorBoundary', () => {
  test('renders ErrorBoundary with ErrorPage as FallbackComponent', () => {
    render(<ReactErrorBoundary />);
    expect(ErrorBoundary).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        FallbackComponent: expect.any(Function),
        onError: expect.any(Function),
        onReset: expect.any(Function),
        children: undefined,
      }, {});            
  });

  test('passes children to ErrorBoundary', () => {
    const children = <div>Hello World</div>;

    render(<ReactErrorBoundary>{children}</ReactErrorBoundary>);
    expect(ErrorBoundary).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      FallbackComponent: expect.any(Function),
      onError: expect.any(Function),
      onReset: expect.any(Function),
      children: <div>Hello World</div>,
    }, {});  
  });

  test('logs error message when onError is triggered', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log').mockImplementation();
    const error = new Error("Test error message");

    render(<ReactErrorBoundary><div>Error occurred!</div></ReactErrorBoundary>);
    
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Error caught!', error);

    spy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

When I run the third test, I get the following error:

```
ReactErrorBoundary › logs error message when onError is triggered
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

I think it is because I am mocking react-error-boundary but even when I modify that mock it does not work. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Why are you mocking `react-error-boundary`? Have you decided what logic do you want to assert?

Answer (score 0):

I advocate for actually testing the real code as much as possible. Mocks just make your code tightly coupled and often lead to contrived tests.

This is how I'd approach it:

```
import ReactErrorBoundary from '../../components/ReactErrorBoundary';
import ErrorPage from '../../components/ErrorPage';
import { logger } from '../../services/logService';

// these mocks aren't mocks, per se, they're spies so you can assert
// that the functions have been called
jest.mock('../../services/logService', () => ({
  logger: jest.fn(),
}));
jest.mock('../../components/ErrorPage')

// this part is only really needed for typescript
const ErrorPageSpy = jest.mocked(ErrorPage);
const loggerSpy = jest.mocked(logger);


describe('MyErrorBoundary', () => {

  // setup your test fixtures
  const error = new Error('bad')
  const MyErrorComponent = () => {
     throw error;
  }
 
  test('renders the ErrorPage when an error is thrown', () => {
    // render a component that throws a real error and triggers
    // the behaviour your want to test
    render(
      <ReactErrorBoundary>
        <MyErrorThrowingComponent/>
      </ReactErrorBoundary>
    );

    // alternatively, you can just assert that your screen contains the content of your <ErrorPage/>
    expect(ErrorPageSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

  });

  // instead of checking "called with", just assert the content is on the screen
  test('passes children to ErrorBoundary', () => {
    const children = <div>Hello World</div>;

    render(<ReactErrorBoundary>{children}</ReactErrorBoundary>);
    epxect(screen.queryByText('Hello world')).toBeInTheDocument()
  });

  // again, render a component that throws an error so that the real behaviour of your ErrorBoundary is triggered
  test('logs error message when onError is triggered', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log').mockImplementation();

    render(
      <ReactErrorBoundary>
       <MyErrorThrowingComponent/>
      </ReactErrorBoundary>
    );
    
    
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Error caught!');
    expect(loggerSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(error);
  });
});
```